# pass contextmenu parent as CommandParameter

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, treeviewitem, commandparameter

i have a HierarchicalDataTemplate for a TreeViewItem, in the template i have a contextmenu and i want to pass as CommandParameter the ContextMenu parent - i.e the TreeViewItem owner that was right clicked at the moment, is there a way to do that? 
here is my template:

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    x:Key="ServerTemplate"
    DataType="{x:Type models:Server}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChannelTemplate}">
    <StackPanel
        Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu
                FontSize="14"
                FontFamily="Arial">
                <MenuItem 
                    Header="{x:Static p:Resources.ServerOperations_CommunicationSettings}"
                    Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.ServerCommunicationSettingCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Parent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
                </MenuItem>

            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <Image 
            Source="{Binding ImageURL, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}"
            Margin="0,0,2,0"
            Height="25"
            Width="25"/>
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding ServerName}"
            Foreground="White"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: You want the TreeViewItem or the DataContext of TreeViewItem to pass to command?

Comment: Ok. I have added an answer. See if that helps.

Comment: btw by saying DataContext of the TreeViewItem do u mean the Server itself (line 3 DataType="{x:Type models:Server}" ) or the DataContext of the window containing the TreeView?

Comment: I meant the instance of Server. I have updated that as well in the answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the TreeViewItem by getting `PlacementTarget of ContextMenu` which will be `StackPanel` and its `TemplatedParent` will be `ContentPresenter` and its `TemplatedParent` will be `TreeViewItem`. So this will work:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.TemplatedParent.TemplatedParent, 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                            AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
```

*PlacementTarget (StackPanel) --> TemplatedParent (ContentPresenter) --> TemplatedParent (TreeViewItem)*

---

Ideally it's not a *good idea to pass UI components to ViewModel*. You should pass data i.e. DataContext of TreeViewItem as you can always play with that.

In case you want to **pass `Server` instance i.e. `DataContext` of TreeviewItem**, you can simply do `"{Binding}"` since MenuItem will inherit it from StackPanel.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

Comment: you are that what i meant sorry for the confusion, but your way of passing the DataContext doesn't work(it causes the contextmenu to be non repsonsive for the user), apparently all is needed is CommandParameter={Binding} thing is that now the contextmenu is not responsive for the first time u right click to open, and from the second time it works fine...

Comment: It works at my end though. But yeah you are right MenuItem will inherit `DataContext` as well. So simple binding will work too. I will update in answer.

Comment: `contextmenu is not responsive for the first time` - What do you mean by this? Small sample in my code and it all works fine for me. Do you have `CanExecute` on `ICommand` which is most likely cause for disabling it?

Comment: my bad... it was my CanExecute method that didn't work properly, for some reason the first time u call CanExecute when an item is right clicked the DataContext is null, but if u simply send the parameter for the execution method it passes correctly... weird... thanks a lot for your help man!