# WPF Command Binding of ContextMenu Item inside ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, itemscontrol, commandbinding

My Application consists of a `MainWindow` with a `ContentControl` and I change the ViewModel depending on the selected menu.

One of the UserControls I display as content contains the following `WrapPanel`:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ConnectionSelectCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=InstanceName}"
                                Style="{DynamicResource DashboardButton}">
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                                              Command="{Binding ConnectionRemoveCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `Command` on the `ContextMenu` doesn't work because it tries to call `ConnectionRemoveCommand` on the `Connection` object instead of the `ConnectionViewModel` which is the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`.

**How** do I bind the `Command` to the `ConnectionViewModel` with the `CommandParameter` being the `Connection` object?

Comment: I believe the question here is about `CommandParameter` and not `Command`! Can you check this link if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448749/pass-contextmenu-parent-as-commandparameter

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9994241/1997232).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bind the `Tag` property of the `Button` to the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl`, you could then bind to it using the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ConnectionSelectCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=InstanceName}"
        Style="{DynamicResource DashboardButton}"
        Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                    Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.ConnectionRemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```